# HDF5DotNet in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, hdf5

I'm trying to compile the HDF5DotNet librabry. I'm using the "HDF5DotNet source and examples" from http://www.hdf5.net/.

I can compile the library with Visual Studio 2008 and 2010 in Virtual machines. Still I need to get it running in Visual Studio 2012 and get the following errors:

```
Error 1: error C2668: 'System::Array::Copy' : ambiguous call to overloaded function ObjectReference.cpp, 30, 1, HDF5DotNet

Error 2: error C2668: 'System::Array::Copy' : ambiguous call to overloaded function RegionReference.cpp, 30, 1, HDF5DotNet

IntelliSense: more than one instance of overloaded function "System::Array::Copy" matches the argument list:
- function "System::Array::Copy(System::Array ^sourceArray, System::Array ^destinationArray, int length)"
- function "System::Array::Copy(System::Array ^sourceArray, System::Array ^destinationArray, long long length)"
```

I do understand the error but I am not aware of how to avoid it. The application is currently build for x86 but I would like to have the option to compile the dll for x64 later on.

Comment: I nearly forgot posting the issue here. You just need to typecast the variables passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just typecast the constant to the int.

```
Array::Copy(a, m_rr, (int)H5R_DSET_REG_REF_BUF_SIZE);
```

Comment: But as far as I understand RobaL compiles not his code. Do you think this is mistake in the original code? Thx! Welcome on SO.

Comment: I did the typecast already months ago. Forgot to post the solution. In fact I took the code straight from the webpage so the problem is in the library itself.